# Converting string timestamp into date

Tags: postgresql, date, timestamp, type-conversion, postgresql-9.1

I have dates in a postgres database. The problem is they are stored in a string field and have values similar to: "1187222400000" (which would correspond to 07.08.2007).
I would like to convert them into readable dates usind some SQL to_date() expression or something similar but can't come up with the correct syntax to make it work.

Comment: Can you provide a second value with its associated date?

Comment: Could the value of '1187222400000' above actually correspond to '2007-08-15 17:00:00'?

Comment: That is possible. I have the same data in another database where only the date is shown but it's entirely possible that behind it there is also a time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There really isn't enough information here for a conclusion, so I propose this 'scientific-wild-ass-guess' to resolve your puzzle. :)

It *appears* this number is **UNIX 'epoch time' in milliseconds**. I'll show this example as if your string field had the arbitrary name, 'epoch_milli'. In postgresql you can convert it to a time stamp using this statement:

```
SELECT TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE 'epoch' + epoch_milli * INTERVAL '1 millisecond';
```

or using this [built-in postgresql function](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/functions-formatting.html):

SELECT to_timestamp(epoch_milli / 1000)

either of which, for the example '1187222400000', produces the result

```
"2007-08-15 17:00:00-07"
```

You can do some of your own sleuthing with quite a few values selected similarly to this:

```
SELECT to_timestamp(epoch_milli/1000)::DATE
FROM (VALUES (1187222400000),(1194122400000)) AS val(epoch_milli);
```

"Well, bollocks, man. I just want the date." Point taken.

Simply cast the timestamp to a date to discard the excess bits:

```
SELECT to_timestamp(epoch_milli / 1000)::DATE
```

Of course its possible that this value is a conversion or is relative to some other value, hence the request for a second example data point.

Comment: Answer. Thanks. In fact working in CARTO there seem to be a few things that are different but your to_timestamp() sent me in the right direction.
I had to convert first into biginteger and then into timestamp but the result is perfect: 
to_timestamp(NULLIF(date_field, '')::bigint /1000)